How can I add resizable split panels in Angular 9.1?
I tried adding resizable splitter ribbon for asset view, tried with primeng, kendo, angular-split library but not working. Either have compatibility issues with the angular version of project or compatible library version not supporting splitter component.
Is there any way to add resizable split panel
Even tried adding custom logic but no luck:
export class AppComponent {

  private isResizing: boolean = false;
  private startY: number = 0;
  private startTopPanelHeight: number = 200; // Initial height of top panel
  private startBottomPanelHeight: number = 200; // Initial height of bottom panel

  topPanelHeight: number = this.startTopPanelHeight;
  bottomPanelHeight: number = this.startBottomPanelHeight;

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {} // Inject ChangeDetectorRef

  @HostListener('document:mousemove', ['$event'])
  onMouseMove(event: MouseEvent) {
    if (this.isResizing) {
      const deltaY = event.clientY - this.startY;
      this.topPanelHeight = Math.max(0, this.startTopPanelHeight + deltaY);
      this.bottomPanelHeight = Math.max(0, this.startBottomPanelHeight - deltaY);

      // Manually trigger change detection
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }
  }

  @HostListener('document:mouseup')
  onMouseUp() {
    if (this.isResizing) {
      this.isResizing = false;
      this.startTopPanelHeight = this.topPanelHeight;
      this.startBottomPanelHeight = this.bottomPanelHeight;
    }
  }

  onMouseDown(event: MouseEvent) {
    const target = event.target as HTMLElement;
    if (target.classList.contains('splitter')) {
      this.isResizing = true;
      this.startY = event.clientY;
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}

<div class="split-container">
  <div class="top-panel" [style.height.px]="topPanelHeight" style="background-color: aquamarine;">
    Top Panel Top Panel Top Panel Top Panel Top Panel Top Panel Top Panel Top Panel Top Panel Top Panel
  </div>
  <div class="splitter" (mousedown)="onMouseDown($event)" (mouseup)="onMouseUp"></div>
  <div class="bottom-panel" [style.height.px]="bottomPanelHeight" style="background-color: chartreuse;">
    Bottom Panel Bottom Panel Bottom Panel Bottom Panel Bottom Panel Bottom Panel Bottom Panel Bottom Panel Bottom Panel Bottom Panel
  </div>
</div>

.split-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.top-panel,
.bottom-panel {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto; 
}

.splitter {
  cursor: ns-resize;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}


Can you please try with npm
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-split-demo-cjcxrg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
